# Debug mode allowing potentially dangerous requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I've just come across an issue which has me a bit baffled.

In one of our MVC applications, we had an issue on the UAT server where a form post was resulting in a "Potentially dangerous request" error, but it wasn't picked up on the DEV server, or local DEV testing.

After a bit of debugging, the actual cause of the error was a typo when using knockout.js where missed parentheses meant that instead of an observable value being added to the form, the JavaScript function sitting behind the observable was being added. Ok, fine, my bad, easy fix.

What I'm having trouble understanding is why this wasn't causing issues on our DEV environment.

During local testing, I managed to recreate the error by changing
`<compilation debug="true" />` to `<compilation debug="false" />`, but I didn't think that would change any of the validation rules regarding form posts.

So, my question is basically, why does changing from debug mode to non-debug mode seem to allow a potentially dangerous request through.

Comment: Any other differences in the web.config between DEV and Production? Maybe request validation is disabled in the dev.web.config? `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` See [Request Validation in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider I did think of that, and there wasn't that I could see, but I did also recreate the issue by changing only that flag while debugging locally, and I know that property isn't present in the web.config I was working with.

Comment: Might it simply be a UAT caching issue? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prashant_upadhyay/2011/07/14/why-debugfalse-in-asp-net-applications-in-production-environment/